# how do you find the auto-generated delta table for AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

How do you find the delta tables that are created when you set up Datastore for an amplify project? When looking at my tables on either AppSync or DynamoDB all I see are the regular tables plus NONE_DS. IS NONE_DS related to it somehow?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "delta tables", but "NONE_DS" is typically used as a placeholder variable when making some sort of change with AWS Amplify.